# Cant redirect from one action to another MVC4

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I am new to MVc4 and trying to pass a parameter from one Action to another (in another controller)

```
public ActionResult Index(ViewModel.Example search)
            {

            if (search.Request != null)
            {
                Session["RoomTypeID"] = search.Request.RoomTypeID;
                Session["Breakfast"] = search.Request.Breakfast;
                Session["Currency"] = search.Request.Currency;
            }

            vm.listRoomRate = GetDataIndex(vm.Request);
            _UserSession.SearchRoomRate = vm;
            return RedirectToAction("SearchResult");
        }



[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult New(ViewModel.Rate.RateViewModel vm)
        {
        if (vm.NewRoomRate.Currency == null)
            vm.NewRoomRate.Currency = "IDR";

        var NewData = _RoomRateService.NewRoomRate(vm.NewRoomRate.RoomTypeName, vm.NewRoomRate.Breakfast,
                                     Convert.ToDateTime(vm.NewRoomRate.CheckInFrom), Convert.ToDateTime(vm.NewRoomRate.CheckInTo), vm.NewRoomRate.sun, vm.NewRoomRate.mon, vm.NewRoomRate.tue,
                                     vm.NewRoomRate.wed, vm.NewRoomRate.thu, vm.NewRoomRate.fri, vm.NewRoomRate.sat, vm.NewRoomRate.Currency, vm.NewRoomRate.SingleRate,
                                     vm.NewRoomRate.DoubleRate, vm.NewRoomRate.TripleRate, Convert.ToDecimal(vm.NewRoomRate.Commision), Convert.ToInt32(vm.NewRoomRate.Allotment), vm.NewRoomRate.CloseSelling,
                                     vm.NewRoomRate.FreeSell);

        if (NewData == null)
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("failed", "Error has occured");
            return New();
        }

        ViewModel.Rate.RateViewModel test = new ViewModel.Example();
        test.Request = new ExampleData();
        test.Request.RoomTypeID = Convert.ToInt32(v..exampleVM2);
        return RedirectToAction("Index", new {search = test.Request });
    }
```

I get an error about the parameter dictionary but I have no idea on what the problem is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

errors about the model dictionary indicate that you are passing an "Apple" and the action is expecting an "Orange" so to speak.

in effect your action is expecting a parameter of type "ViewModel.Example" but you are sending a parameter of type "ExampleData"

change your last line to this:

```
return RedirectToAction("Index", new {search = test});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your test.Request object is type of ExampleData class but your index action expecting ViewModel.Rate.RateViewModel instance.
So Populate new ViewModel.Example object with your data and pass it to the RedirectToAction method.
    `return RedirectToAction("Index", new {search = Your ViewModel.Rate.RateViewModel instance });`

Make sure parameter names for redirect action should be same as Index action parameter name